# Virtual Host location on cPanel Server

Tags: cpanel

As the title says. whats the path to the virtual hosts on a cpanel server?

I need to add a virtual host and have a couple of paths and would like to know where it is meant to be rather than where will work.

Comment: Did you find anything from googling? Show your research.

Comment: I found httpd-vhosts.conf, httpd.conf, proxy.conf (not sure about the last)

Comment: Typically httpd-vhosts.conf is included in httpd.conf and is where you are 'meant' to add them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have usr/local/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found mine inside this file: /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

And related file for suspended accounts were found in /etc/apache2/conf.d/include/account_suspensions.conf

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But after some searching i found another solution.
The solution is using ssh. I used PuTTY (you can download it here https://www.putty.org/).

Once you install and open PuTTY : in the "Host Name(or IP address)" form write the name of your website (or the ip of the server if you don't have a domain yet).
Once you are in it will ask you for a login and then a password.
The login and the password are the same as for the cpanel.
SSH might not be available, it depends on cpanel.
So you might need to contact the support to enable it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You have to be more specific about the problem. Perhaps one day the link may be broken also.